# Wordpress the_content('more') fails to display <--more-->

Tags: wordpress

I'm having an annoying problem with my `wordpress 3.5` blog .

`the_content()` function fails to display the short version of the posts on the first page / index page, and it shows the content of the posts in full .

my current `the_content()` codeline from `loop.php` file is:

```
<?php the_content('Read more...'); ?>
```

I did try to search the wordpress forums stackoverflow and codex and i tried this :

```
<?php 
global $more;    // Declare global $more (before the loop).
$more = 0;       // Set (inside the loop) to display content above the more tag.
the_content("More...");
?>
```

but it does not work.

Any ideea what this problem could be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added a `<!--more-->` tag to your page content where you'd like to show the more link?  Taken from the Codex on [the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt):

> Sometimes it is more meaningful to use only `the_content()` function. `the_content()` will decide what to display according to whether `<!--more-->` tag was used. The `<!--more-->` tag splits post/page into two parts: only content before the tag should be displayed in listing. Remember that `<!--more-->` is (of course) ignored when showing single post/page.